# Show link whenever attribute not present

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 4. In my view, I find myself doing this a lot:

```
<% if spot.phone.present? %>
  <%= shop.phone %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Update", edit_shop_path %>
<% end %>
<% if spot.email.present? %>
  <%= shop.email %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Update", edit_shop_path %>
<% end %>
```

The tag `<%= link_to "Update", edit_shop_path %>` should be shown whenever the attribute is not present. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a partial:

```
<% if attr.present? %>
  <%= attr %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Update", edit_shop_path %>
<% end %>
```

then just reuse this partial:

```
<%= render "partial", attr: spot.phone %>
<%= render "partial", attr: spot.email %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ternary operator:

```
<%= spot.phone.present? ? shop.phone : (link_to "Update", edit_shop_path) %>
```